# How would non-atomic matter behave

Tags: alternate-reality

In a roleplaying game I'm running, the players have just visited an alternate universe with fundamentally different chemistry. I haven't figured it all out yet, but the big thing that I have figured out is that in that universe, things aren't made of atoms, or any sort of discrete particle. Instead, the substance is basically the same no matter how far you zoom in. Also, in its pure state, the primary substance of that universe simply passes kinetic energy through and out the other side rather than moving, but only in its pure state.

The players have just taken a handful of dirt from that universe back to their own world, which is basically a modern Earth, and they intend to study that dirt in a high school chemistry lab. The thing is, I have no real idea what sort of results or weird properties I should expect them to find. How would non-atomic matter of this sort behave? Which tests and properties are dependent on atomic level interactions in ways that a uniform substance wouldn't mimic?

Edit: Here's an attempt to give more about the physics and chemistry in order to help with more meaningful answers, though as I said above, I haven't got this all figured out yet.

The most common substance of this universe is called Aether (its the same one I mentioned the kinetic energy properties of above). When pure, it has a density of about 5 grams per cubic centimeter and perfectly conducts kinetic energy. It can be combined with or separated from other substances using chemical interactions that use light as an energy source, since it is otherwise unaffected by things happening to it.

There is also a substance called gleam (might change that, but I don't have anything better yet), that is normally liquid and absorbs light before slowly releasing it.

There would also be more substances, with a variety of properties in order to allow for life, including amorphous, semi-liquid life, but I haven't figured out what all I need/want for that yet. (Yes, I recognize I should have figured out more of this before putting it in my game)

There are no gases native to this universe, though portals from it bumping into Earth's universe have resulted in it gaining an atmosphere of air from our universe.

This universe is conical, with a fixed gravity towards the point, and things that reach the edge re-entering at the point across the cone from where it reached the edge. Using this, there is an effectively dome like structure near the point of the cone which plays the role of a planet.

Comment: Sorry, if you don't describe the physics of this matter how are we supposed to make anything other than a wild guess? On a side note, I think the sentence "it simply passes kinetic energy through and out the other side rather than moving,"  makes no sense. Kinetic energy IS bound to motion.

Comment: @L.Dutch Well, the fact that it is not made out of atoms should have an effect on its properties, and that's the primary thing I'm trying to ask about. Regarding the kinetic energy bit, I mean that if something impacts it, then whatever is on the far side will move instead of it. In effect, it transfers the kinetic energy rather than ever having the kinetic energy itself. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: Not really. Let me help you: if I ask you "how does the liquid in this bottle behave? It's not Merlot." without telling you anything else, how will you answer?

Comment: "*In effect, it transfers the kinetic energy rather than ever having the kinetic energy itself. Does that make any more sense?*" it just sounds like a dense material. Imagine an iron rod. If you keep it next to your chest and somebody hits it on the other side, you'd feel it.

Comment: Also, probably worth noting - the alternative reality sounds like a video game or something where things are essentially whole, rather than composed of particles. If it's *real*, then it sounds...manufactured. In nature it is easier to build up larger things from smaller ones. If you have the freedom to create a universe, then it's usually easier to have a top down approach. Although, even then it's usually preferable to have "building blocks" of some sort.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I can see your point, though there are general properties of liquids that could be talked about. Something I've come up with since posting the original question is that it wouldn't really have a temperature, since heat is from vibrating atoms. Still, I'll try to add some details.

Comment: @VLAZ For your comparison to the iron rod, yes, its very much like that, except it does it perfectly, to the point that it doesn't move at all, and by any other measure, it is significantly less dense. ... Actually, I just realized that on Earth, that would cause problems when it doesn't adjust course with the planet's movement. Well, I did specify only in a pure state, and I guess I can handle random chunks of material flying off into space if they purify it on Earth.

Comment: "*it wouldn't really have a temperature*" more like it would have a temperature of 0K, I suppose.

Comment: @VLAZ That is a fair assessment of the temperature, which concerns me for hopefully obvious reasons. How hard would it be to justify it not causing anything touching it to rapidly freeze?

Comment: I'm not that well with physics but *usually* to cool something you transfer some of the vibrations of particles (heat) to something with less vibrations ("colder"). And vice versa. If you do happen to have something *extremely* cold (0 Kelvin) surrounded by "hotter" particles (more than 0 Kelvin), chances are that the cold one would increase temperature. However, if you have no *particles*, I really don't know how that would work. Sounds like it's probably similar to vacuum.

Comment: It being infinitely divisible, undifferentiated, and uniformly distributed "stuff" implies no chemical reactivity at all since there are no electron shells for ordinary atoms to interact or bond with.  (That really leaves open the question about how it even manages to be a solid at all as there's no description about how it binds with itself to have solid properties.)

Comment: Not being made of the same kinds of particles as our atoms, it would fall through atomic matter as if it weren't even there. Or, if it somehow has electric or magnetic charges (reasonable if it is possible to see it), maybe not entirely as if it weren't even there, but even so, it would pass through solid atomic matter rather than being blocked by it. So merely holding onto and containing it for study would be a challenge.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan From our [help/on-topic], "World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, *in short, everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire universe you want to build.*" And for emphasis, [Real Life cannot be an overriding limitation on any question unless specifically requested](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8143/40609). The entire point of this site is embodied by this question and the fact that it does not conform to "reality."

Comment: @JBH The querent specifically asked about the chemistry with real world matter in the second paragraph, therefore that rule does not apply.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Sure it does. You might explain why our chemistry and that universe's chemistry are incompatible - but you can't argue that the other universe must have atoms. That's the whole point of the question: given the incompatibilities, what could our erstwhile adventurers test for and find?

Comment: @JBH  I'm confused; are you referring to someone else's response?  As you can see from my response, my answer was precisely about how the hypothetical material is incompatible with real-world chemistry and that insufficient information was provided to deduce enough about it's self interaction to guess other properties.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan No, I'm referring to your comment. My point is you're locked into the idea that just because the material doesn't conform to real life that it's impossible to infer properties. I don't believe that's true. Use your imagination. If you were handed a hunk of stuff and couldn't test it chemically, what properties could you infer from other forms of analysis?

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Yup. So? Why does that change anything? While the location would be logical to the story, it does not impose any kind of relationship on the material. I apologize for being argumentative. I'll stop, but I've been frustrated for more than a month at how *literally* people are taking questions and trying to impose the restrictions of real life upon them. We shouldn't need to pester the OP about answering the question, "if you're setting is a HS chem lab, are you expecting chemistry-based results or something else?" If you think about it, the OP didn't use the [tag:chemistry] tag.

Answer (score 2):

**I like this idea**

Your worlds are made of, proverbially, cheese. Cool!

"Infinitely divisible" isn't unreasonable. We once thought that the components of an atom were as small as one could go. Then we discovered subatomic particles. We're still hunting for even smaller particles, but we have imagined what "infinitely small" means: a photon having no mass exhibiting its lowest energy state would be as small as small can get. Maybe that's not infinitely small since it's definitely definable... but I figure when you get to the point of dividing by zero, you've hit infinitely small... am I right or am I right?

*At least that's what we think...*

I'm not a fan of assuming that what we know today is in any way shape or form the end-all of understanding. Personally, I think it'll be a while yet before what we don't know becomes a smaller quantity than what we know.

So, you have a planet of proverbial cheese. And I can cut that cheese into smaller and smaller bits until I get to that final massless bit, the *pheese,* which might act like both a particle and a wave. Some kinds of cheese are kinda wavey... so I'm good with this!

- We know this substance, if struck hard, will transfer that energy to the other side without loss. All that means is that it's a [perfectly elastic substance](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/elacol.html). That's physics 101. For those of you who haven't enjoyed that class, this is a bit like what a superconductor does with electricity, so we're within suspension-of-disbelief here.

What other properties could we infer?

- If there's nothing on the other side to absorb the energy, the energy will hit the edge of the cheese and bounce. How it bounces would depend on the shape of the surface. There would be no vibration (I always thought it funny that a flexible collision that dissipates energy is considered an *inelastic* collision, but there you are). I'm going to ignore a number of basic physics things here (like how billiard balls act...), because I think it's cool that you just invented the multiverse's first infinitely chargeable battery.

*If you had a cylinder of this material that was magically suspended in space and pounded one of the circle ends with a hammer, every strike would add energy to what is already bouncing around inside the cheese. Without any limits imposed on the material (there would be some, but let's ignore it for now) you could pound forever and the energy would simply add to the total. It would remain there until something touched the cylinder. I'd hate to be the thing that touched the cylinder, but to be fair, I'm not exactly out trying to touch the two poles of a car battery, either.*

- The material would be frictionless as any friction would make it inelastic. This would likely be a bit of a problem for your planets.
- You can't damage the cheese! The benefit of being perfectly elastic is that you can't break a chunk of it off. No matter how hard you hit it (even with itself!), the kinetic energy passes harmlessly to the other side. This might cause you grief with the concept of dirt because you're assuming *something* shredded the cheese... but it actually can't be shredded.
- In fact, if two chunks of cheese are brought into contact, they instantly bond to become a single chunk of cheese that can't be bent, broken, manipulated...

***I'm beginning to have a bit of trouble with your perfectly elastic cheese... I can't figure out how you get dirt.***

Unless something in your universe breaks down the cheese! Maybe the ubiquitous cosmic radiation causes the cheese to weaken and break apart. That would mean the substance is susceptible to electromagnetic radiation, which would suggest it's to some degree *opaque* (another characteristic). The only practical problem with this idea is that it would suggest there are weaknesses in the cheese that allow the breakage, so it's not perfectly uniform (homogeneous).

On the other hand, if we assume the cheese is crystalline in nature and is infinitely divisible in the same way a fractal is... then we have weaknesses between the crystal formations that could kinda justify the radiation turning the cheese into dirt.

*Or the cheese has impurities, like blue cheese, but those impurities would not pass kinetic energy without absorbing a little something in the form of heat... that could justify making dirt, too.*

So, there's a start for you. But I would like to point something out...

*This material cannot exist in our universe just as material from our universe cannot exist in that universe. If the two come into contact, either the cheese reacts with nothing in our universe or it explodes upon contact with anything and everything in our universe. As much as I love the idea for your game, you can't have a non-atomic material that can be tested with atomic materials. They're incompatible as are the rules of physics that govern them. So, "realistically" (*cough*) your only options are nothing reacts with it or anything it touches causes it to explode.*

Comment: Thank you for the through analysis. I did specify that the perfect transfer of kinetic energy was only for when it was in a pure state, and it can be caused to combine with other substances through means besides kinetic force, so the dirt is presumably a non-pure version.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of atom came from the ancient Greek Democritus - at that time nothing was known about the structure of matter like today but he proposed there must be something small enough to be "uncuttable" - which we know isn't true of what scientists first thought were the smallest unit of matter when chemistry developed to produce elements from their compounds. The name for what we call atoms remains and now we understand it to mean something more specific to chemistry and those elements we have in the periodic table.

When we come to Quantum Physics what we have is that the energy of particles is not continuous but only exists in specific amounts - the quanta. The wave function that describes that is however a continuous function and I have seen it proposed that one could indeed describe the entire universe as one giant equation where we would otherwise generally speak of much smaller systems.

The smallest unit of *measurable* space time is known as the Planck length but we don't know if that means the structure of the universe is discrete or continuous. So as far as our own universe goes we don't know if it is infinitely divisible either.

So what we can say is that things like electrons are emergent phenomena arising from the evolution of the quantum wave function describing it - leading to all the observations of wave/particle observations. This observation has lead to people wondering about how the hell that makes sense - with some going with the "many worlds" theory and others with a "hidden variables" theory. The former saying that for anything we observe as being an electron in one place it could be there's another evolution of time where it was elsewhere. The latter says there is something we can't measure that determines that.

With that one could say that your world really isn't that different to ours in many ways at the fundamental level - the really difficult thing is that if you start from the roots with the equations describing these small behaviours it's not clear what might be possible if you really wanted to be hardcore in how the physics would allow things to be at a larger scale.

However if I were to try and pull that apart the thing that really springs out is how you would ensure that gases aren't a thing. It would imply that things actually can't really be divided and have to be stuck together. You need some sort of negative space to allow things to be distinct from each other. In our world I would think of that as basically being places where energy isn't there - matter is really high density locations of energy as per E = mc^2.

So what I am envisioning given what you describe is a place where there must be a force that is ensuring that it is possible for complex structures to emerge working against the Aether - holes as it were preventing everything just becoming one lump as it moves inexorably towards the centre of gravity in your universe.

Comment: Hello Cyborg! Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Thanks for contributing to this question! When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and read through the first two bullets of our [help] to understand what we're all about.